# Confused about PAR(Pixel Aspect Ratio) in video

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, h.264, aspect-ratio, ntsc

#### Part1

According to [Here](https://github.com/ob-encoder/x264-obe/blob/master/doc/vui.txt)

```
SAR_x   DAR_x * height
----- = --------------
SAR_y   DAR_y * width
```

for example: width x height = 704x576, DAR = 4:3 ==> SAR = 2304:2112 or 12:11

---

So we can derive

```
SAR_x    width      DAR_x              width
----- x -------- = -------  ==> SAR x -------- = DAR
SAR_y    height     DAR_y              height
```

According to [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_aspect_ratio#Introduction), we can get: `SAR × PAR = DAR`.

Which means

```
       width
PAR = -------
       height
```

---

#### Part2

According to [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale2ref)

> main_dar, mdar : The main input video’s display aspect ratio. Calculated from `(main_w / main_h) * main_sar`.

we can derive

```
            main_w                        width
main_dar = -------- x main_sar ==> DAR = -------- x SAR
            main_h                        height
```

Again proof that:

```
       width
PAR = -------
       height
```

---

#### Part3

But from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_aspect_ratio), we can get 2 images
[image]

Which means PAR(Pixel Aspect Ratio) is the ratio of single pixel, apparently this definition of PAR is not the same as the result that we get from above(part1 & part2).

So I'm confused about this, anyone who can explain this?

---

#### Edit

Search "Non-square aspect ratios of common video formats" within [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_aspect_ratio#Introduction), you can see a table which I already take a screenshot below

[image]

Comment: One another into your collection: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/picture-aspect-ratio#pixel-aspect-ratio

Answer (score 2):

SAR and PAR are the same. `sample` is the generic term for the elementary "particles" of media. `pixel` is specific to video, whereas audio has `sample`.

`sample aspect ratio` is the term used in modern video codec standards.

The only equation to know is `SAR * width / height = DAR`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but if SAR and PAR are the same, then why the SAR and PAR in the table are different?(I've edit the question and add a table in it).

Comment: What the Wikipedia article calls SAR (storage aspect ratio) is not a term or a metric used in industry standards. It exists on Wikipedia and sites that derive their content from it.

Comment: It turns out that S stands for Storage, not Sample, now I'm a little clearer, thank you.

Comment: Only on Wikipedia. SAR stands for sample aspect ratio, in ffmpeg and industry specs.

Comment: Okay, I got it.

Comment: [Presumably](http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=84400) this started two decades ago from the GSpot developer wanting a somehow more intuitive terminology (since different codecs handle the concept differently.. and H264 was barely newborn), and then getting [spread](http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=80910&page=58) in encoding circles. The [wikipedian](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Pixel_aspect_ratio&diff=244171114&oldid=244077967) probably [adopted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Pixel_aspect_ratio#Sample_Aspect_Ratio) this convention while educating himself there.